# Sencha Architect 4.3 for M1 chip

Tags: apple-m1, sencha-architect, architect

Sencha Architect 4.3 on Apple M1 (Monterey 12.0.1)
cannot upgrade a old project made with SA 4.2.9 on Apple Intel.

"Project Needs Upgrade(s)" window appear, after 30 minutes remains the same window with "Loading instances 323/322".

The animation on Sencha logo is running, but nothing else.

Any idea to fix it?

Dependencies:
java version "1.8.0_111"
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]

[Sencha Architect 4.3 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVicY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Update:
two computer:
1) Apple Intel with BigSur
2) Apple M1 with Monterey

I have old projects works corrent on SA4.2.9

On both my computer i download from "support.sencha.com" the correct release for SA4.3.

Opening my old project, both SA43 ask me to upgrade CMD for project.
In both show a window with "Loading instances 40/39", same window after 2 hours. No error appear.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
same problem on two different computer:

1. Apple Intel with BigSur
2. Apple M1 with Monterey

I have old projects works correctly on SA4.2.9
On both my computer i downloaded from "support.sencha.com" the correct release for SA4.3 for each computer.

Opening my old project, both SA43 ask me to upgrade CMD for project.
In both there is a window with "Loading instances 40/39",
same window after 2 hours.
No error appear.

[Sencha Architect 4.3 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jKyw.jpg)